# Do I have to pay rent to my father when the home is owned by a family LLC I partially own?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, limited-liability-company, rent

I am inquiring about an LLC-owned property that I am renting. I, along with my three brothers, are owners of the LLC.

My parents bought the house originally but then the LLC bought the property and house that the property is on.

Could anyone tell me if it is legal for my dad to charge me rent for the property that I am renting? Wouldn't any profit from my rent go to the LLC holders, myself included?

Would this differ in certain states or is it the same across the board?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have an LLC with partners, then you probably pay an accountant a decent amount of money to prepare the taxes.  I would ask him.  The answer depends on a lot of things.

Comment: Trying to clarify the actual question here.  The LLC is the owner and landlord.  Who is the tenant?  You or your dad?

Comment: Who are you renting the property from? Who is your agreement with?

Comment: What does your dad have to do with the LLC exactly?

Comment: Perhaps your father is the **manager** of the LLC?  If he is, then he is in charge of the LLC's day-to-day business. Managers do not have to be owners.  Usually an LLC's Articles of Organization and Operating Agreement will explain who owns what, who is the manager, how to call a meeting of owners, how to manage the manager, etc.

Comment: Also, this question could benefit from being narrowed a bit.  For example, it would be better to click edit and add your state than to ask people to explain this in all 50 states.

Comment: Perhaps your father is short of money in his monthly budget and this is a way to ask for help without hurting his pride.

Comment: @donjuedo: Given the constellation with a Dad who used to be owner, this may not be a question of pride but one of the key points of the construction... Transfer of ownership (anticipating inheritance) but keeping usufruct (roughly: right to live there, or to rent out the house in order to earn money e.g. if Dad needs to move into nursing home) is a fairly well-known construction over here in Germany.

Comment: Are all 4 brothers living in the house or just you? If just you, then yes, why wouldn't you pay rent to cover the use you're getting from the house?

Answer (score 30):

Your dad isn't an owner, that is equivalent to any stranger down the street charging you rent for a house your company owns, unless he lives there.

If your dad lives there, then he is beholden to the tenant agreement with the landlord which is the LLC.  If the LLC lets him charge rent, then he can charge it. The real question then becomes, why is he charging you. Do you live there too?

And finally, why are you guys doing things like this at all? You didn't explain anything relevant to the question. Do you need to live in the house? Does he need to live in the house. Why even act like it is an investment property if this is the primary home of your parents and one of the LLC owners? Why don't your parents just join the LLC alongside your brothers? Why not set up a trust instead? So many problems

Comment: You should remove the requests for clarification from the answer and post them as comments on the question. They don't belong here.

Comment: nah, they are useful things to think about, the question marks are more of a ... coincidence

Comment: There's a crucial question missing: What exactly were the terms when the ownership was transfered from parents to LLC? There may well be terms that make Dad someone very different from the stranger down the street. E.g. parents could have transferred ownership but kept usufruct for the rest of their life.

Answer (score 13):

> Could anyone tell me if it is legal for my dad to charge me rent for
>   the property that I am renting? Wouldn't any profit from my rent go to
>   the LLC holders, myself included?
>
> Would this differ in certain states or is it the same across the
>   board?

Let's see if I understand correctly.

- Your parents originally purchased the property
- At the time you rented from them and lived there
- Then, you and your three brothers purchased the house from your parents
- You and your brothers now hold it via an LLC
- The LLC isn't using your dad to collect the rent for them

If this is all true, then your parents no longer have any financial stake in the property. Any rent you pay should go to the LLC.

As far as "is it legal" you can simply tell you dad that you don't owe him rent. He could choose to take you to court and would lose, if my understanding is correct.

This has nothing to do with certain states. Your dad isn't the owner. The LLC would collect the rent.

Comment: The only situation I can think of where OP would still owe rent to Dad is: In case Dad rents the house from the LLC, he can sublet to OP. Then OP has to pay rent to Dad and Dad has to pay rent to LLC.

Comment: Whether or not the dad can sublet to the OP depends on the rental contract with the LLC, which is again entirely up to the OP and his brothers.

Comment: @chepner Contracts are up to two parties; the contract with the LLC can exist even if the owners of the LLC don't want such a contract.

Comment: Yes, if somebody other than the three brothers negotiated the contract.

Comment: axsvl77's answer reminded me of a 2nd construction in addition to subletting (and one that fits better with the Dad + kid being (partial) owner + is asked to pay rent constellation): Dad keeping usufruct after transfering ownership

Answer (score 12):

Let me take a guess at the arrangement:

1. Your Dad purchased the property.
2. Your Dad, as he is getting old, didn't want his estate to pay taxes on his death, so he gave the property to the LLC which is in you and your brother's name. This way, you will get a larger inheritance.
3. When he did this, he had a gentlemen's agreement with you guys that the property was his in reality, and yours legally. This way, when he dies, you won't pay estate taxes. This arrangement is fairly common.
4. He is charging you rent based on the idea that the property is his in reality and yours only "legally". Probably this money is going toward maintenance of the property.

If I am right, then legally, you don't have to pay rent. However, if you didn't pay rent, you'd be going back on your agreement (#3) with him. Without getting into the [parable of the prodigal son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Prodigal_Son), this is an odd situation.

Is the rent at least lower than market rate? It seems like it might be time to go off on your own and rent an apartment not affiliated with your family. Then, the property you legally own be managed by your dad, and he can use the revenue to maintain the property you will receive when he passes.

Comment: Note that a clever person might actually make the gentlemen's agreement an actual legal one; ie, enter into a contract as part of the sale of the property to the LLC to lease the property back for 1$ per year ending on both your father and mother's death, with zero liabilty for the state of the property on the part of your father and mother.  Such "cleverness" would depend on local juristiction and hiring a lawyer who thinks of it.  In short, the OP isn't showing all the cards, the OP needs a lawyer.

Comment: Unless the parents estate and/or house is worth greater than $5.5 million, estate tax is NOT the issue at play here. This strategy might avoid probate in some states, which is a good thing. Writing a valid will would avoid probate in most states too.

Comment: An estate worth more than $5.5 million is not that rare these days. Many a coder who contributes to SE might have this much money after 2 or 3 decades of work, with some decent investing.

Comment: @axsvl77 Indeed, millenials will probably _need_ that much for retirement, thanks to inflation.

Comment: Over here (Germany) there's a very official legal construction for step 3+4: usufruct (Nießbrauch). The ideas (in addition to clear inheritance tax/issues) are that once the ownership of the house is transfered, Dad still needs to live somewhere, so he kept the right to live in the house for the rest of his life. However, it is not unheard of that elderly people need to get care that they cannot in their home - and that can be costly. So Dad keeps usufruct, so in case he moves out (e.g. into a nursing home) the rent earned from the house is his and can help paying the nursing costs.